# Remove quotation marks from php number

Tags: php

I know this has been asked before, however nothing seems to work

I have following json output:

"coordinates": [
                    "18.366466",
                    "29.898110"
                ]

However, the output I want is:

"coordinates": [
                    18.366466,
                    29.898110
                ]

```
$coordinates = array($result->lat, $result->lng);

$output[$i++] = array(
                    "type" => "Feature",
                    "geometry" => array("type" => "Point",
                    "coordinates" => $coordinates),
                    "properties" => array(
                        "ID" => $result->id,
                        "icon" => $result->icon,
                        "tags" => $tagsForJson,
                        "title" => $result->title,
                        "description" => $result->description));
```

Trim, str_replace and all of those functions are not working

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? Are they causing problems?

Comment: Try this
`$coordinates = array(floatval($result->lat), floatval($result->lng));`

Comment: floatval($result->lat) worked thank you!

Comment: @Dave I have to sent a specific response and it may cause problems (I assume)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking to do is [type-cast](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) this data into an float.

After preparing (trimming, etc) the string with the numbers, you can do something like this:

```
$coordinates = array((float)$result->lat, (float)$result->lng);
```

Or to cast the whole array at once, more simply you could utilize [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [floatval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

```
$coordinates = array_map('floatval', $coordinates);
```

Comment: intval will make it lost the decimal. :)